# Sign in with Apple: Not able to download apple-developer-domain-association.txt

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

I'm not seeing any option to download "apple-developer-domain-association.txt" for domain verification (I did that couple of months back) now seems like UI changed!

I follow the below steps 
https://help.apple.com/developer-account/?lang=en#/devde676e696

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same.
For a couple of apps, roughly two months ago, I had to add that `.txt` file to validate.
Less than a month ago, I ended up realising Apple has changed their Domain and Return URL verification without relying on uploading the `apple-developer-domain-association.txt` to verify the ownership.
As you see, now it needs just to support `TLS 1.2+`

Comment: domain already have TLS 1.2 is there any reference you have about this. I'm referring https://help.apple.com/developer-account/?lang=en#/dev77c875b7e

Comment: As this one explains: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/?lang=en#/dev1c0e25352 there is no longer the need of the `.txt` file to be uploaded to verify it.

Comment: Could you connect? How Did you validate your domain?

Comment: hey @HaroldoGondim, straight after adding it, the domain got validated